# Kubernetes Restrict Node to run labeled pods only

Tags: kubernetes

we would like to merge 2 kubernetes cluster because we need to establish a communication between the pods and it should also be cheaper.

Cluster 1 should stay intact and cluster 2 will be deleted. The pods in cluster 2 have very high requirements for resources and we would like to create node pool dedicated to these pods.

So the idea is to label the new nodes and also label the pods that were part of cluster 2 before to enforce that they run on these nodes.

What I cannot find an answer for is the following question: How can I ensure that no other pod is scheduled to run on the new node pool without having to redeploy all pods and assigning labels to them?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems you have to solve:

1. Stop cluster 1 pods from running on cluster 2 nodes
2. Stop cluster 2 pods from running on cluster 1 nodes

Given your question, it looks like you can make changes to cluster 2 deployments, but don't want to update existing cluster 1 deployments.

The solution to problem 1 is to use [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/). You can taint your cluster 2 nodes to stop all pods from being scheduled there then add tolerations to your cluster 2 deployments to allow them to ignore this taint. This means that cluster 1 pods cannot be deployed to cluster 2 nodes and problem 1 is solved.

You add a taint like this:

```sh
kubectl taint nodes node1 key1=value1:NoSchedule-
```

and tolerate it in your cluster 2 pod/deployment spec like this:

```yaml
tolerations:
- key: "key1"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value1"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Problem 2 cannot be solved the same way because you don't want to change deployments for cluster 1 pods. This is a shame because taints are the easiest solution to this. If you could make that change, then you'd simply add a taint to cluster 1 nodes and tolerate it only in cluster 1 deployments.

Given these constraints, the solution is to use [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity). You'd need to use the `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` form to ensure that the rules are always followed. The rules themselves can be as simple as a node selector based on labels. A shorter version of the example from the linked docs:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: a-node-label-key
            operator: In
            values:
            - a-node-label-value
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

Comment: Alternate to affinity for node selection:
`spec:
  nodeSelector:
     a-node-label-key: a-node-label-value`

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem 2 is the easy one, because I have to redeploy these pods anyway, but I could not find the solution for Problem1. I will accept your solution after we made the necessary changes.